# Intersecting Boundary Layers in XFLR5

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, airfoil, boundary-layer

I am analyzing an airfoil called RevE-HC. While doing a type-1 analysis, I encountered that the BL is intersecting towards the trailing edge. The panels are refined and the geometry is also smooth. Any clue as to why this is happening and how to resolve this? Similarly, the Cp vs x graph shows a double peak towards the LE and a sharp peak at TE. What does that mean? Any help would be appreciated.

The data is for zero AoA.

The data:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]